# How to make journald increase logs storage capacity?

Tags: log, storage, systemd-journald

I would like to have persistent logs via journald. I created `/var/log/journal` and reloaded the service. Now logs are saved on the disk. But the log size limit is low.

I added `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`. (`Storage=persistent/auto` doesn't matter, I tried both).

```
[Journal]
Storage=persistent
#Compress=yes
#Seal=yes
#SplitMode=uid
#SyncIntervalSec=5m
#RateLimitInterval=30s
#RateLimitBurst=1000
#SystemMaxUse=
SystemKeepFree=10G
SystemMaxFileSize=1G
#SystemMaxFiles=100
#RuntimeMaxUse=
#RuntimeKeepFree=
#RuntimeMaxFileSize=
#RuntimeMaxFiles=100
#MaxRetentionSec=
#MaxFileSec=1month
#ForwardToSyslog=yes
#ForwardToKMsg=no
#ForwardToConsole=no
#ForwardToWall=yes
#TTYPath=/dev/console
#MaxLevelStore=debug
#MaxLevelSyslog=debug
#MaxLevelKMsg=notice
#MaxLevelConsole=info
#MaxLevelWall=emerg
```

As you can see I only changed each journal file size to 1Gb and told that I want 10Gb free on the disk.

But `journald` tells me that he only has 4Gb log storage capacity.

```
$ sudo systemctl status systemd-journald
...
jan 20 15:44:26 host systemd-journald[1218]: System journal (/var/log/journal/) is 4.5G, max 4.0G, 0B free.
jan 20 15:44:26 host systemd-journald[1218]: Journal started
```

What did I miss?

```
$ systemctl --version
systemd 229
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to increase `SystemMaxUse=`

From https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html

`SystemMaxUse=, SystemKeepFree=, SystemMaxFileSize=, SystemMaxFiles=, 
 RuntimeMaxUse=, RuntimeKeepFree=, RuntimeMaxFileSize=, RuntimeMaxFiles=`

The first pair defaults to 10% and the second to 15% of the size of the respective file system, but each value is capped to 4G.

Comment: It is also preferable to elaborate your response in a way which is particular to the problem they're facing, hence not just putting a link to a certain file.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be tricky because there are many default values that are set. To fix my problem it was important to understand two types of parameters. Those that limit a *global* log size and those that limit log size of *individual* log files. The defaults for the individual log files are **1/8** of the size of the global log size. So if you want to make sure your log can really grow as high as global limit you also have to set the file size limit to the same value:

```
SystemMaxUse=10G
SystemMaxFileSize=10GB
```